# PowerShell: Move file where file path is stored in variable

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to move a file for which I stored the file path in a variable. I can see the correct values in the variable and on the screen but I’m getting a FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound error and I don’t see where I’m going wrong.

Here is what I’ve got:

```
$importfolder    = ".\PowerShell_script\" 
$outputfolder    = ".\PowerShell_script\Output\"

$filesTXT = ".\PowerShell_script\*.txt" 

#Get all the file names for each of the *.txt files
$list = Get-ChildItem -Path $filesTXT | select Name

#Extract image file information for each file and change the file path before moving it
foreach($file in $list) {
    #Extract image file name from line 7 by removing the file path information
    $imagetemp = Get-Content $file.Name | Select-Object -Skip 6 -First 1 
    $imagename = Split-Path $imagetemp -leaf  
    $imagefile = $importfolder + $imagename

    echo "`n" "Image filepath in file" $imagetemp
    echo "`n" "Image name" $imagename
    echo "`n" "Image" $imagefile
    
    #Move image to output folder
    Move-Item $imagefile -Destination $outputfolder
}
```

Below is a sample of my TXT file which contains the wrong location of the image file path:

```
0001117945
14102022
0001056.98
GBP
0000000.00
0000000.00
\\GLORSAWA01\EHIShared\Remittance\UK01\UKI_REM_COL2f1dbb99993647eea2000.pdf
```

Comment: So in `$imagetemp` you're storing the content of a file, then you're using `split-path` on that same variable, but you don't want to split path on the content of a file.... you want to split the path of the actual filepath. The error you are likely getting is probably `Split-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.`

Comment: The error I get is with the last line "Move-Item $imagefile -Destination $outputfolder". It says Move-Item : Cannot find path because it does not exist. But it does exist.

Comment: You can also just use `Select-Object -Index 6` instead. According to your script logic, it should display `".\PowerShell_script\UKI_REM_COL2f1dbb99993647eea2000.pdf"`, correct? Are you sure that there is no spaces after the file name? I would suggest a `(Split-Path $imagetemp -leaf).Trim()`.

Comment: I would say, avoid using relative paths, thats probably causing this error. and use `Join-Path` instead of `$importfolder + $imagename`

Answer (score 0):

change the following line

```
$imagetemp = Get-Content $file.Name | Select-Object -Skip 6 -First 1
```

to

```
$imagetemp = Get-Content ($importfolder + $file.Name) | Select-Object -Skip 6 -First 1
```

you are trying to read a file that is in the $importfolder folder, but you seem to be running the script from the parent folder

Comment: There were indeed spaces after the file name and I used what https://stackoverflow.com/users/20223471/metzli-tonaltzintli suggested and used (Split-Path $imagetemp -leaf).Trim() which solved the issue.

Comment: Good to know it is resolved. Gratz